# Empty date and time in mysql table

Tags: php, xml, datetime, curl, google-calendar-api

I am inserting date and time in date-time column where I am getting a value only for date and time I am assigning it manually, to make the date-time to match MySQL date-time syntax I did something like :

```
if($start==NULL && $end==NULL){    
    $start = '01:00:00';
    $end = '02:00:00';    
}

$eve_start = $year."-".$nmonth."-".$date." ".$start;
$eve_end = $year."-".$nmonth."-".$date." ".$end;
```

Now I am getting **year in $year**, **month in $nmonth**, **date in $date** and $start as my start time and $end as end time.

$eve_start should look like 2012-06-01 01:00:00, also i am getting proper values in place of $year, $nmonth, $date when I printed them individually, but when I printed $eve_start or $eve_end I got only year part printed.

Also in database the corresponding value for date-time inserted as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 where it must be 2012-06-01 01:00:00.

I am getting these values from XML tags, I am importing Google calendar events using XML format and CURL.
Now for simple events i get start and end dates with time. But when it is an All day event I dont get time in the xml file, I only get start and end date. Now what i am doing is whenever all day event comes I check for start and end time, if it is null I assign static values to them. I don't have any problems in inserting simple events in my db only prob is with ALL day events

Comment: The code you gave - while unnecessarily complicated - looks fine. Check your input parameters...

Comment: @user1852701 
What you get after printing $eve_start and $eve_end only year?
then it's clear that all variable are null except year, they don't have any value.Please echo all $year ,$nmonth,$date and $start individually and check whether all values are coming ot not!

Comment: Hello, currently what i am doing is, i am adding start and end time only to those events which are kept as ALL day events which doesn't have Start and End time. I think the parameters I am passing are correct because it's not working only for ALL day events, other simple events which has start and end time are getting inserted in database without any problem.

Comment: Hello, @sandip I did mention than I am printing variables individually and I get all the values but when I echo $eve_start then it's printing only year

Comment: @user1852701 dude can please provide the code of echoed values with it's output

Comment: this is year 2013

this is month 01
this is date 4
this is my complete datetime :: 2013    and the code is as follows
`echo "this is year ".$year."<br>";
echo "this is month ".$nmonth."<br>";
echo "this is date ".$date."<br>";
echo "this is my complete datetime :: ".$year."-".$nmonth."-".$date." ".$start;`

Comment: why don't you try to add it as datetime format and get year month and day in mysql query.?

Answer (score 1):

you should store time in timestamp format using mktime(). And retrive it using date() functin.

Answer (score 0):

You should format this using date() function

```
$start_dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($eve_start));
$end_dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($eve_end ));
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for the reply but it's not working, it is giving me 1970-01-01 01:00:00 instead of 2012-06-01 01:00:00

Comment: I just did this. I assigned some static values to the variable $year, $nmonth & $date. I did everything what we mentioned here. It works well for me.. Output is 2012-06-01 01:00:00
2012-06-01 02:00:00

Comment: Umm I am still getting the same value. Is there any other solution?

Comment: i think the problem is on your input only.. Check your variables $year, $nmonth and $date..

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MySQL DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

MySQL store default date time as yyyy:mm:dd h:i:s.

Below code will help you to solve issue.

```
SELECT
      DATE_FORMAT(YOUR_DATE_FIELD,'%Y') AS YOUR_YEAR,
      DATE_FORMAT(YOUR_DATE_FIELD,'%m') AS YOUR_MONTH,
      DATE_FORMAT(YOUR_DATE_FIELD,'%d') AS YOUR_DAY
from your_table
```

and to store the date time field in MySQL you can simply add NOW() mysql function to store current date and time.

`INSERT INTO table ( data , date ) VALUES('".$date."',NOW() );`

can you please edit your question and add some more detail regarding problem.

1. from where that three variables are coming from.
2. what value you are assigning to those three.
3. are you getting those three from MySQL query if yes then my above solution will solve it.

if its still not solving issue then the problem may not be in the script, but in the **browser cache**

run the code and see the outcomes that will helps.

Comment: The values I am getting are from coming from xml file. I am importing google calendar events and using CURL and xml format. Now for simple events i get start and end dates with time. But when it is an All day event I dont get time in the xml file, I only get start and end date. Now what i am doing is whenever all day event comes I check for start and end time, if it is null I assign static values to them. I don't have any problems in inserting simple events in my db only prob is with ALL day events.

Comment: as per i know when event is for all day google calendar return true for all_day.

Comment: It would dump only date and no time like this When: Fri 4 Jan 2013 for all day and for simple ones When: Thu 3 Jan 2013 10:00 to 11:00 this.

Answer (score 0):

1. PHP side: I tried your same code and PHP prints date-times correctly for me.

   http://codepad.org/mKmNM9Yu
2. Mysql side:  Make sure the column type is '**datetime**'. And makesure you have assigned the date variable correctly in the **insert** query.